# Can I use regex in fail2ban logpath?

Tags: fail2ban

I am using `CETNOS 7`,`yum install fail2ban`,in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`,I want to set:

```
[DEFAULT]
apache_error_log = /var/log/httpd/*error_log
/home/websites/.*?/log/errorlog
```

to express:

```
    [DEFAULT]
    apache_error_log = /var/log/httpd/*error_log
    /home/websites/site1/log/errorlog
    /home/websites/site2/log/errorlog
```

Then,I can use `%(apache_error_log)s` in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` as below:

```
[apache-noscript]

port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s
```

Is this OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fail2Ban `logpath` doesn't use regular expressions but ***glob* Unix filename pattern matching**.

> [jail.conf (5)](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-jail.conf/),  `logpath`
>
> filename(s) of the log files to be monitored, separated by new
>   lines. Globs -- paths containing `*` and `?` or `[0-9]` -- can be used
>   however only the files that exist at start up matching this glob
>   pattern will be considered.

Rules:

- `*` matches any number of any characters (including none)
- `?` matches any single character
- `[abc]` matches one of the listed characters
- `[a-z]` matches one character in a (locale-dependent) character range
- inside the brackets, `!` can be used for negation (POSIX systems)
- **path separator characters i.e. `/` are never matched**.

Therefore, `/home/websites/*/log/errorlog` will do.

Comment: can I add `tail ` after `/home/websites/*/log/errorlog`?

Comment: You can't: `logpath` only takes paths to log files to search. Fail2Ban handles reading the files internally, not through a pipe.

Comment: see https://websavers.ca/improve-fail2ban-io-performance

Comment: Oh, there's such an option, too! It just has the same name as the command. Then, sure you should be able to use it.

Comment: If I add `tail`,fail2ban can only read `10` lines log.Will that cause `findtime` invalid?

Comment: That's only when it starts. When new logs starts to build, Fail2Ban aren't limited to 10 lines anymore. Consider using `tail` if the log files are huge, making the Fail2Ban startup slow.